# How to update vuejs component data with methods?

Tags: vue.js, methods, vue-component

I am trying to re-initialize some input data of my component with a method. However, I get an error while compiling this code, yet I am convinced that the syntax is correct...? Does anyone see the error? Or can explain why this error happens?

TEMPLATE

```
<div class="text-center padder-v">
  <button @click="queryReset" class="color-button">Réinitialiser les filtres</button>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      queryLevel: "",
      queryCycle: "",
      querySubject: ""
    };
  },
  watch: {
    queryLevel: {
      handler() {
        if (this.queryCycle != "" || this.querySubject != "") {
          queryReset();
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    queryReset() {
      this.queryCycle = "",
      this.querySubject = "",
    }
  } //compiling error
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

statements should be ended with a semicolon `;` not comma `,`

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      queryLevel: "",
      queryCycle: "",
      querySubject: ""
    };
  },
  watch: {
    queryLevel() {
        if (this.queryCycle != "" || this.querySubject != "") {
          this.queryReset(); // use `this.queryReset()` 
        }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    queryReset() {
      this.queryCycle = ""; // Should end with semicolon
      this.querySubject = ""; // Should end with semicolon
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... no comment

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Don't understand why you're using comma at the end instaead of ";"

this.queryCycle = "",
this.querySubject = "",